# Does a convergent sequence of norms of a vector space always converge to a norm?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

I thought that just as the sequence of norms $||x||_p :\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ converges to $||x||_{\infty}$ maybe there is some result that proves that every convergent sequence of norms of a vector space (perhaps under certains restrictions) converge to another norm, is there some proposition about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be a vector space and $\|\cdot\|_n$, $n\in\Bbb N$ be a sequence of norms and assume that $\|\cdot\|_n\to\|\cdot\|$ pointwise. Then $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm iff $\|x\|\ne 0$ for all $x\ne 0$.
Indeed, all properties of norm clearly transfer to the limit except the condition that non-zero vectors have non-zero norm.